# Dúvida ao sobrescrever atributo com Apache Tiles

Tags: java, aplicação-web, apache-tiles

Estou estudando um pouco sobre o Tiles e me surgiu uma dúvida. Tenho a seguinte definição:

```xml
<definition name="main" template="/views/templates/main.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="titulo" value="##" />
    <put-attribute name="header">
        <definition template="/views/templates/header.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="first" value="/views/menu/first.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="second" value="/views/menu/second.jsp" />
        </definition>
    </put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/views/templates/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Estou fazendo um template para uma tela de crud, no qual essa tela será composta por 2 painéis. Um com campos de pesquisa e outro com uma tabela de resultados. Porém o formulário de pesquisa e os resultados serão diferentes para cada tela obviamente, então gostaria de sobrescrever os atributos `search-fields` e `result-table` nas páginas que extendam essa definição.

Para isso criei a seguinte definição:

```xml
<definition name="crud" extends="main">
    <put-attribute name="content" >
        <definition template="/views/templates/crud-page.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="search-fields" value="override" />
            <put-attribute name="result-table" value="override" />
        </definition>
    </put-attribute>
</definition>
```

Definido esse template, tentei criar uma página que usasse esse template da seguinte forma:

```xml
<definition name="crud-users" extends="crud">
    <put-attribute name="search-fields" value="/views/crud/usuario/search.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="result-table" value="/views/crud/usuario/result-table.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Vejam os arquivos .jsp -

main.jsp:

```xml
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <main>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />    
    </main>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /> 
</body>
```

crud-page.jsp:

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="search-fields" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="result-table" />
```

Porém o que aparece na tela é "override" e não o conteúdo das páginas que sobrescrevi. Como proceder em casos desse tipo? Qual erro estou cometendo?